# WordPress Elementor custom loop query not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WordPress site using Elementor (viewable at https://rugbyboroughfc.co.uk/fixtures/#womens). I'm attempting a custom query to retrieve posts containing an Advanced Custom Field (ACF) with a date stored in the format 'jS F y, H:I,' showing only results occurring after the current time.

Here's my function (please pardon the echoes—I wanted to confirm its functionality).

```
function my_query_by_different_order( $query ) {
    $now = current_time('timestamp'); // Get the current UNIX timestamp
    $when = get_field('match_date_&_time');

    if (empty($when)) {
        // Handle the case where 'match_date_&_time' is empty
        echo '"match_date_&_time" is empty';
        return $query;
    }

    $when_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F Y, H:i', $when);
    if (!$when_date) {
        // Handle the case where 'match_date_&_time' couldn\'t be converted to timestamp
        echo '"match_date_&_time" couldn\'t be converted to timestamp';
        return $query;
    }

    $when_timestamp = $when_date->getTimestamp();

    echo 'now = ' . $now . ' -- when = ' . $when_timestamp;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'match_date_&_time' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'    => 'match_date_&_time',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value'   => $when,
            'type'    => 'DATE', // Use DATE type for ACF date fields
        )
    ) );

    // Add a filter to log the SQL query
    add_filter( 'posts_request', 'log_query' );

    return $query;
}
```

The query seems to be returning all results and not just those after NOW. Can anyone please help me?

I've tried various ways to compare the dates and time by converting them, but nothing seems to work. I either get all the results, no matter if they came before '$now' or after. OR I get none.

Thanks

Comment: You do not filter after $now, you filter after $when.

Comment: You might find this helpful - [Query upcoming posts](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/#query-upcoming-posts)

Comment: @shadow thanks, but that's not worked. Still produces the same results

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I compared the `match_date_&_time` field against the current time correctly.

```
function my_query_by_different_order( $query ) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $now = current_time('Y-m-d H:i'); 

        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'match_date_&_time' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'match_date_&_time',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value'   => $now,
                'type'    => 'DATETIME', 
            )
        ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_by_different_order' );
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry that's not changed the results.

Comment: What do you see in the results?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I see the same as seen here https://rugbyboroughfc.co.uk/fixtures/#womens

Comment: Ensure that the date format in $now matches the format stored in the 'match_date_&_time' ACF field. If they don't match, the comparison may not work as expected.